# Composite functions yeah

Tags: functions

I'm trying for the GRE so that I can apply for grad school in 2017. I've been working well through calculus and algebra. I'm making good progress but functions has been a challenge. Take this for example. Could somebody ensure I'm doing this right and if not, point me in the right direction?

If $f(x) = x^2 - 3$ and $g(x) = x + 3$ find

$\text{i) } f(g(x))\\ 
\text{ii) } g(f(x))$

---

So the first one, am I right in assuming I need to multiply $x$ with $g$ first, and then $f$?

So $x$ multiplied $x$ with $x + 3$ and then multiply this by $x^2 - 3$? 
So $x^2 + 3$ and then $x^4 - 9$?

I think I'm going right but can't help it's wrong too?

Comment: "Multiply" is the wrong word. "act on $x$ with $g$ first, ..." would be better.

Comment: This problem is about composition of functions, not multiplication of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I got it!

For anyone liking future help I figured it out with my textbooks:

$$f(g(x))\\ 
g(x) = x + 3\\
f(x + 3) = f(g(x)) = (x + 3)^2 -3$$

---

$$g(f(x)) = g(x^2 - 3) = x^2 - 3 + 3 = x^2$$

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct.

Comment: For the third line: it is better to write $f(g(x))=f(x+3)=\cdots$.